# How to find the number of candidates in an election given the number of ways a voter can vote

Tags: combinatorics, combinations

This is the question,

`In an election, the number of candidates is 1 greater than the persons to be elected. If the voter can vote in 254 ways, then the number of candidates is?`

The answer is as follows,

[image]

Can you explain to me how we came to a conclusion,

`C(n,1) + C(n,2) ... + C(n,n-1) = 254`

Comment: If you added in $C(n,0)$ and $C(n,n)$ which are both 1, this would be the binomial expansion of $(1+1)^n$. So you're trying to solve $2^n = 254+1+1$.

Answer (score 3):

The answer to the question is contained in the condition of the problem. How exactly can a voter vote?  He can vote for one candidate, he can vote for 2 candidates, and so on, he can vote for $n-1$ candidates. Let's number all candidates by numbers from $1$ to $n$. Then the number of ways to vote for $k$ $(0<k<n)$ candidates is the number of ways to choose $k$ numbers from $n$ without regard to order, i.e. $C(n,k)$ (the number of combinations of $n$ elements by $k$). It remains to sum over all $k$ from $1$ to $n-1$.